# Get template information from an envelope

Tags: docusignapi

The /`accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/templates` API call can return which templates were applied to any of the doucments within an envelope, and returns information like this:

```
{
   "templates":[{
   "name":"String content",
   "templateId":"String content",
   "uri":"String content"
   }]
}
```

Is there no way to determine on which pages the template is applied?  When you upload a new document to an envelope, you're able to say 'this template starts on page 5', but is there a different call to get that information, or be able to determine that information in some way?

If not, what might be a way to determine that?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to determine which templates are applied to which pages within an Envelope.